# how to add a button on the product page in sqaure space

Tags: web, squarespace

I wanted to add a PREORDER button to some products in the shop page under add to cart option. Since it is a preorder button it will be added to some of the products only. It there a way to do it in square space because I want to link that preorder button to celery. I know how to do it by code injection by adding code in the header of the site but I dont want the button I add to be general I want it specific to a product. I hope  someone is going to help me on this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this unless you use header code injection - as you mentioned. In order to make the code product specific, I would check for the existence of a particular element that only exists on the product page you are looking for.

For example, if you were to add a dummy code block to that particular products page:

```
<div id="myprod"></div>
```

And then in the header code you could check for existence of that id and then add your button:

```
if ($('#myprod').length) {
  //add your button 
}
```